# Is it possible to set JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel dynamic ids?

Tags: gallery, plugin-nextgen-gallery

I usually get JJ NextGen JQuery Carousel with the short code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[jj-ngg-jquery-carousel gallery="2" width="120" height="120" visible="4" scroll="4" auto="0" wrap="circular" order="sortorder" gap="0" skin_class="jcarousel-skin-lango150"]' ); ?>
```

which is related to the nextGen gallery(id=2), previously created on the admin area.

So, I'm trying to set this code on a single-{post type}.php, to be able to dynamically associate the gallery of each post, and retrieve their respective images, like:

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- do-stuff -->
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[jj-ngg-jquery-carousel gallery="name-given-to-gallery" width="120" height="120" visible="4" scroll="4" auto="0" wrap="circular" order="sortorder" gap="0" skin_class="jcarousel-skin-lango150"]' ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.